# how to use anaconda python in command prompt

Tags: python, anaconda3

I learned from other posts that in order to use python installed by anaconda, I need to set up environmental variable shown below. As you can see, I put `C:\Users\RT008840\Anaconda3\python.exe` and `C:\Users\RT008840\Anaconda3\Scripts` at the top among other variables.

[image]

However, when going back to the command prompt with `where python`, the output is still `C:\Users\RT008840\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` instead of my python path from anaconda `C:\Users\RT008840\Anaconda3\python.exe`

Any missing steps here?

[image]

P.S. The reason I want to run python in the command prompt is that I will have to run some python scripts in the SQL Server 2008 in the future with xp_cmdshell that suggested from [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/different-approaches-to-execute-python-in-sql-server/).

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 is *completely* unsupported, for ~2.5 years. If you upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server, you'll actually be able to run Python Scripts natively within SQL Server; Python was added as a supported external language in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: I understand that but unfortunately I cannot persuade the company to upgrade the system. That would be a lot more easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove**`python.exe` from the path. Only the folder location is needed. 
 To verify this location, open the anaconda prompt and then use `where python`. It detects the correct python location. 
 Also I don't think that keeping the path at the top is mandatory, it will work even if it is not on the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add to the bin folder path to the `PATH` environment variable.
It will be like:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\anaconda3\Library\bin
```

After adding path to the environment variable, you cam simply type `conda` on your local command line and it will work.

- use `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\<user_name>\anaconda3\Library\bin` in your current command prompt
- Use your computer settings to do that forever

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you need to use `Anaconda prompt` instead of normal `command prompt`